# Is Math.Pow(10, Math.Abs(1)) equal to 10?

Tags: c#

I'm currently maintaining a code of a former colleague, and found following code (example):

```
double someValue = 20, someResult;

someResult = (Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(someValue / (Math.Pow(10, Math.Abs(1))), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * Math.Pow(10, Math.Abs(1))) + 10) - someValue;
```

and i wonder, why he used `Math.Pow(10, Math.Abs(1))` instead of `10`?
Is it because of inaccuracy or some sort of?

The result is the same, if the code is changed to:

```
someResult = (Math.Round(someValue / 10, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 10 + 10) - someValue;
```

Comment: Maybe it is a part of algorithm and this is only for readability.

Comment: Since the result is afterwards rounded and trimmed to an int, your *new* code will most likely return the exact same result in every relevant case with the added bonus of improved readability.

Comment: The integer `10` can be represented exactly in floating point, so this is likely just some "exact" translating of a formula of some sort. Even if floating point made sense, you wouldn't write `Math.Pow(10, Math.Abs(1))` instead of `10.0`. But look for other instances of this pattern (`Math.Pow(x, Math.Abs(y))`). There may be (forgotten) method to the madness.

Comment: The only reason I can think of why this ever existed is that when your colleague wrote this code, he was still tinkering with the exact values and just happened to decide on `10` in the end.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer my suspicions also , it passed the unit test, all good

Comment: Sad truth in life: there is not always a reason for weird and bad code written by our predecessors.

Comment: The worst part about maintaining someones crappy code, is when you work out its yours

Comment: To answer your actual question: [Yes, it is equal to 10](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/r3VmFL), not even a tiny floating imprecision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only difference between using `10` instead of `(Math.Pow(10, Math.Abs(1))` will be the type. If you write `10` in code the compiler will treat the number as an `int`. `Math.Pow` however will return a `double`.

Sometimes this could make a difference. For example if `someValue` was an `int` then `someValue/10` would be using integer division and thus might not do what you expect. In this case though `someValue` is a `double` so you will use floating point division either way.

So yes, you are safe here replacing the `Math.Pow` call with just `10`.

As for why it is like this - most often I find this sort of code exists because it was originally more complicated and then got simplified. eg it might have originally been something like `Math.Pow(10,precision)` or something like that which needed the method call. Then somebody decided to always make precision 1 and updated accordingly without actually simplifying any code such as this that could be simplified.

The *actual* why is pure speculation though. If this is in source control there might be a commit comment that explains it or if not it might allow you to find the author and ask them...

Comment: Thank's for this comprehensibly explanation; though i can't ask the author because of biological reasons.

Comment: I figured that might be the case but felt it worth mentioning in a full answer - the next person to read this may be able to.